# SQL Server: fundamental design issue?

Tags: sql-server

The director of the company I work for met another director of a software company at a party (this is not a joke !).

The second director told my director that,

'he had spent a fortune abandoning SQL Server' because 'if several people were querying the same table in different ways the database locked up'.  Further, this is a 'known fundamental design issue with SQL Server where each query competes for maximum resources until SQL Server locks up after about 7 concurrent queries to the same table'.

Now I know a bit about SQL Server locking and IO and this is news to me.  AFAIK there is nothing *inherent* in the SQL Server architectur that causes such problems.  And SQL Server performs well in the TPC benchmarks, esp on price/performance.

Feel embarrassed asking but I have to be sure - is there any grain of truth to what he said ?

EDIT - after reading some of the comments I thought Id make it clear that I agree its possible to write poorly performing sql in Sql Server, as it is on any db platform.  Sort of asking if there is anyting inherent in the architecture that blocks it out under certain high concurrency conditions irrespective of how well your db/sql is crafted?

Comment: Well, it depends on the query - if it's written in such a way as to hold pessimistic locks then it's possible he observed what you describe - but that would be the fault of the query's author, not SQL Server itself!

Comment: Voting to close because it's likely to start a religious war.

Comment: When you say 'querying' what do you mean ? inserts ? selects ? updates ?

Comment: -1 @ Stuart - heaven forbid some arguing...very interesting question +1.

Comment: -1 back at you @JonH. Arguing over technical answers leads to better coding; arguing over hearsay leads to never-ending comment chains that are full of noise and fury, and little value. :)

Comment: Sounds a very confused / ill informed assessment. Have you any idea what type of resources the director was talking about and what type of queries (i.e. bog standard `SELECT` queries?). If they were talking about memory CPU time etc I don't see why they would believe querying the same table would be any more problematic than different tables.

Comment: @StuartAinsworth - the difference is there is a definite answer to this.  It's not pure propoganda.

Comment: @StuartAinsworth, what are you suggesting is hearsay?

Comment: Or maybe this is an extremely garbled explanation of a deadlocking problem they had. The "querying the same table in different ways" bit may refer to the recommendation to acquire resources in a consistent order.

Comment: Sheesh; my third comment on a comment chain that I think should be closed  :)  @Abe - I'm referring to the fact that the OP is basing a question on what one director told another director (not the OP) as hearsay.  Has the OP included any research to identify the specific circumstances of poor performance in the question?  Without specific guidelines, this question offers litte more than entertainment value (we get to hear horror stories of "idiot developers" and "idiot directors".  Meh.

Comment: Reality may demand the develoepr to respod to this accusation. Or b eing asked to his opinion. Which makes it a valuable answer to ahve for him.

Answer (score 6):

There is absolutely no truth to this, and the *other* director clearly had one of the following two scenarios in his IT department, which can be found at **very** many firms:

1. No DBA, or the (idiot) director was the DBA, or someone with no DBA qualifications whatsoever was forced to act as the DBA
2. An incompetent DBA or incompetent IT employees who created the DB schema(s) and queried the database in incompetent ways given those schemas. Also, see TomTom's comment to this answer below, which expands and expounds on this item further.

Also, do have a look at SQL Server's market dominance at the moment, before coming to any conclusions of its inability to do something.

That is not to say that SQL Server is perfect and has no "fundamental design issues," such as for example this unbelievable bug you can encounter when using identity columns which practically everybody does for surrogate keys:

[SCOPE_IDENTITY() sometimes returns incorrect value](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=328811)

Comment: So surely your second scenario provides a grain of truth - yes it is possible for the DB to lock up under certain conditions. I'm not for one minute suggesting it's a flaw in SQL Server though !

Comment: Add developers to DBA's that don't understand locking and you get into a very normal scenario. Most developers dont really know ow a database works and "just somehow get their code working". Even SQL eludes them (i.e. COMPELX sql, not the simpel select). This is IMHO the most likely scenario. Some idiot developer complaining and some idiot techl ead buying that and some idiot CTO making a decision.

Comment: @K.Bob it is possible for any properly implemented RDBMS to have performance problems just like it is possible to write a slow application in C++.

Comment: @TomTom, here here, I upvoted your comment!

Comment: @Crispalot - For sure it would, hence I hopefully made myself clear that it wasn't a SQL Server issue as such.

Comment: The inherent problem with SQL Server is that you do, in fact, need a real DBA and programmers with a clue using it.

Comment: @Nikki9696, this is true of any relational database

Comment: Yes. I work on a larger Oracle database (21000 gigabyte space allocated) and geuess waht - we have specialists coding most queries. Especially thsoe aggregating a billion rows. Relational database are highly specialised tools. Airplane pilots must know how to fly. Develoeprs soemtimes dont know their job. Quite often regarding databases.

Answer (score 2):

I know you can lock up SQL accidentally or with some poorly written queries but I wouldnt say it is a design flaw with SQL Server itself.

I have worked on software that was going to be deployed across the UK, 80+ stores all querying the same tables and never had any problems. Our company also produced way larger software built on a SQL database which would have 100s of stores with anything from 10 - 100+ applications all querying / updating the same tables, we had a few issues with deadlock but they were all resolved.

With the right people and knowledge SQL is an amazing tool, when you get any old programmer and make them the DBA you get problems which I suspect has happened here.

When I hear stories like this unless the person telling me is developing some huge enterprise level application I always think if big business can manage to use this application without it giving them huge problems then me saying I cant use SQL in my smaller application is just me doing it wrong.

It would be interesting to know what they migrated to instead of SQL though.

Comment: +1 If we find out what they dumped SQL Server for and whether the same developers find the same fatal flaw in their new DB.

Answer (score 1):

Poorly written queries can result in the behavior he is talking about.  This is not a reason to abandon SQL Server though, it is a reason to look for better developers/DBAs.

Any technology, when used incorrectly can appear to have problems.  There are a number of huge projects out there that are built on SQL Server (including [StackOverflow](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/10/before-you-upgrade-to-sql-server-2008/)).  If what he was describing were a result of SQL Server and not the developers then SQL Server would most likely not even be around...